# @State not updating values in My Custom View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I m working on app with Swift and SwiftUI.

I have @State property of Array which I am updating its items, it is updating.

**But with my Custom View It is not updating.**

My Custom view simple view that handle View. Same code with same property is working but with inner/custom view not updating value.

[image]

```
struct MyItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var text: String
    var id = UUID()
}

struct TempView: View {

    @State var outerItems = [MyItem]()
    @State var innerItems = [MyItem]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            ForEach(outerItems) { entry in
                VStack {
                    Text(entry.text)
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.outerItems.append(MyItem(text: "Inner Item:\(outerItems.count)"))
            }) {
                Text("Add Outer Item")
            }

            Divider()

            CustomView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(innerItems) { entry in
                        VStack {
                            Text(entry.text)
                        }
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.innerItems.append(MyItem(text: "Outer Item:\(innerItems.count)"))
                    }) {
                        Text("Add inner Item")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    @State var content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `@State` from `CustomView` just the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the @state

```swift
   // Wrong
  @State var content: () -> Content 
   // Correct
  var content: () -> Content
```

You can also use @Binding to pass the items array to the CustomView instead.

```swift
    struct CustomView: View {
        @Binding var innerItems: [MyItem]
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ForEach(innerItems) { entry in
                    VStack {
                        Text(entry.text)
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.innerItems.append(MyItem(text: "Outer Item:\(innerItems.count)"))
                }) {
                    Text("Add inner Item")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And for the usage you can do :

```
 CustomView(innerItems: $innerItems)
```